# Is there a way to create a detection/non detection matrix with imperfect detection in R?

Tags: detection

I have a file with detections of 8 species collected from ARUs on 3 treatment types (33 ARUS/ Treatment A and B and 30 on Treatment C). Not every ARU recorded every day during the entire survey period. Looking to find a way to make a Dectection/ Non-detection matrix for each species per day per treatment that includes N/A for a species if the units malfunctioned on a day (vs a 0).
I am a very intro to R person so sorry in advance if this is a stupid question.

I used the splist2presabs function from fuzzySim
ie
spp.presabsReseedDATE = splist2presabs(Reseed_Spp2023,sites.col = "DateDetected", sp.col ="species_code", keep.n =FALSE)

The above code produces a species detection/non detection for each treatment like I wanted, however I am unsure how to trust that the zeros are from a non detection or from an ARU not recording properly.